# Same eigen values giving 2 different eigen vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

For the matrix below I am getting two eigen vectors for a single eigen value

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

characteristic polynomial = $-x^3 + 3x + 2$

for $\lambda = -1 $ I get two eigen vectors:

$(1,0,-1)$ and $(0,1 ,-1)$

How come an eigen value can have more than one eigen vector?

Answer (score 1):

That's no contradiction, that an eigen value has more than one eigen vector. Take the matrix $A=\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right)$. Each vector $v\neq 0$ is an eigen vector of $A$ for the only eigen value $1$.

Answer (score 1):

the eigenvalues $\pmatrix{0&1&1\\1&0&1\\1&1&0} = uu^\top - I, \text{ where } u = (1,1,1)^\top$ are $2, -1, -1$ and the corresponding eigenvectors are $u, u^\perp.$  what you have listed are two linearly independent vectorsin $u^\perp.$

the matrix you have is an example of a rank one perturbation of the identity matrix. their eigenvalues and eigenvectors are easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

I find it strange that people even get surprised about this kind of event. Take, for example, the matrix $I$, the identity matrix and one of the simplest matrices you can think of. *Every* vector is an eigenvector of $I$ for the eigenvalue $1$, so $I$ has a whole lot of eigenvectors for one eigenvalue.

In general, you know that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if the determinant of $A-\lambda I$ is equal to $0$. But that equality only tells you that $\ker(A-\lambda I)$ is not the trivial subspace. It can be anything from a one-dimensional subspace (thus, $A$ would, in a sense, contain "only one" eigenvector), or it can be the whole space, like if $A=I$. Or, it can be anything in between.